# how to extract section to multiple xml from one xml via python

Tags: python, xml, extract

source.xml

```
<root xxx>
    <test>
        <ppp>
            <ppp>
                xxx
            </ppp>
            <ppp>
                yyy
            </ppp>
             ...
             ...
       </ppp>
    </test>
```

there are many among ppp
I want to extract it to single  files :

1.xml:

```
    <ppp>
        xxx
    </ppp>
```

2.xml

```
    <ppp>
        yyy
    </ppp>
```

3.xml and so on

I know it can be achieved by xml.etree.ElementTree
pls kindly give me an example for this, the confusing part is it has double ppp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `xml.etree.ElementTree` module:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# to load xml contents from file use the following:
# tree = ET.parse('source.xml')
# root = tree.getroot()


source = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <test>
        <ppp>
            <ppp>
                xxx
            </ppp>
            <ppp>
                yyy
            </ppp>
       </ppp>
    </test>
</root>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(source)
for k, ppp in enumerate(root.findall('./test/ppp/ppp')):
    tree = ET.ElementTree(ppp)
    tree.write(str(k+1) + '.xml')
```

- `root.findall('./test/ppp/ppp')` - finds all matching elements by path
- `tree.write()` - writes the element tree to a file, as XML

The above code will parse the needed elements and write them into files `1.xml` and `2.xml` respectively

https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: does it work in python2.7.11  and I want to use tree.find() after tree = ET.ElementTree(ppp)

Comment: the solution covers your initial requirements and it should work on python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

In the docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) I found the following sentence:

> Children are nested, and we can access specific child nodes by index:
>
> > >
> >
> > > root[0][1].text
> > >       '2008'

So you should be able to simply call them by Index after getting them out of your first big xml. Hope this is somehow helpfull :)